# Swit 5.1 Adding CoreData to an Existing project But I got this error

Tags: swift5

```
2020-04-05 16:18:10.014238+0530 StayHome[2732:178019] [error] error: No NSEntityDescriptions in any model claim the NSManagedObject subclass 'NotifyDetails' so +entity is confused.  Have you loaded your NSManagedObjectModel yet ?
CoreData: error: No NSEntityDescriptions in any model claim the NSManagedObject subclass 'NotifyDetails' so +entity is confused.  Have you loaded your NSManagedObjectModel yet ?
2020-04-05 16:18:10.014435+0530 StayHome[2732:178019] [error] error: +[NotifyDetails entity] Failed to find a unique match for an NSEntityDescription to a managed object subclass
CoreData: error: +[NotifyDetails entity] Failed to find a unique match for an NSEntityDescription to a managed object subclass
2020-04-05 16:18:10.016103+0530 StayHome[2732:178019] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An NSManagedObject of class 'NotifyDetails' must have a valid NSEntityDescription.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110cb527e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c3e5b20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreData                            0x000000010c939d28 -[NSManagedObject initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:] + 485
    3   StayHome                            0x000000010b94470f $s8StayHome13NotifyDetailsC6entity10insertIntoACSo19NSEntityDescriptionC_So22NSManagedObjectContextCSgtcfc + 111
    4   StayHome                            0x000000010b9447fc $s8StayHome13NotifyDetailsC6entity10insertIntoACSo19NSEntityDescriptionC_So22NSManagedObjectContextCSgtcfcTo + 76
    5   CoreData                            0x000000010c9e767e -[NSManagedObject initWithContext:] + 290
    6   StayHome                            0x000000010b90484f $sSo15NSManagedObjectC7contextABSo0aB7ContextC_tcfcTO + 31
    7   StayHome                            0x000000010b9042b7 $sSo15NSManagedObjectC7contextABSo0aB7ContextC_tcfC + 39
    8   StayHome                            0x000000010b903f7a $s8StayHome13LocalDatabaseV0C4DatayySS_SStF + 282
    9   StayHome                            0x000000010b9079ef $s8StayHome17LocalNotificationC0D0yySS_SStFySb_s5Error_pSgtcfU_ + 223
    10  StayHome                            0x000000010b907f6f $sSbs5Error_pSgIegyg_SbSo7NSErrorCSgIeyByy_TR + 127
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000111afedd4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000111affd48 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000111b065ef _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 788
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000111b071b5 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 476
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000111b12a4e _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 719
    16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000111f7c6fc _pthread_wqthread + 290
    17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000111f7b827 start_wqthread + 15
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same issue and tried several solutions like commenting out

```
@objc(CheatTime)
```

or selecting Current product module in .xcdatamodeld

Nothing worked.

After that I tried to make a fetch request before adding a new object and it worked
So in my cases I've added following code:

```
let request = CheatTime.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<CheatTime>
request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(CheatTime.numberOfHours), ascending: true)]
let fetchedRC = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
try? fetchedRC.performFetch()
```

After that objects were added without a problem, not only for the first object type (CheatTime in my example), but for the second one too (without additional fetch request)